# Markdown (md) and reStructuredText (rst) editor

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

I am in search of a simple WYSIWYG / Rich Text editor which can save the file in Markdown or reStructuredText format. Preferrably  both.

Is there such a tool which runs on Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Try ReText:

> **Description-en**: Simple text editor for Markdown and reStructuredText
>
> ReText is a simple editor for Markdown and reStructuredText markup
> languages.
>
> ReText  supports tabs, live text preview and syntax
> highlighting.
>
> Supported    export formats: HTML, ODT, PDF. It is also
> possible to write custom export    extensions.      It is written in
> Python using Qt libraries.

From `apt-cache show retext`.

---

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install retext
```

Comment: ReText is not WYSIWYG. It has a "live preview" but that is not even close to WYSIWYG. What other options are there?

Comment: retext is great. it even has the --preview switch. however, when i edit the file with vim, it throws a message "This file has been deleted by other application. Please make sure you save the file before exit." do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Typora is a true WYSIWYG markdown editor. Editing in Typora is WYSIWYG, and you can also edit the document's source code directly too. Typora can save documents in both Markdown (.md) and reStructuredText (.rst) as well as several other formats. Typora supports images, headers, lists, tables, code fences, mathematics, diagrams, inline styles, etc.

What makes Typora special is its ability to capture rich content from local applications and webpages directly via copy/paste without losing any of the original formatting and convert it directly into markdown. Typora can capture in this way formatted lists, headings, formatted text, hyperlinks, and images. Typora can also capture some formatted tables depending on how they are formatted,

Typora can be installed from the Ubuntu Software app in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu or from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo snap install typora-alanzanattadev
```

[image: formatted table in Typora]

Comment: it is commersial, free to evaluate for some perioed of fime for linux, not open source. Just so readers know.

Answer (score 0):

I use [atom](https://atom.io/) for Markdown (md) files. Using `Ctrl+Shft+M` it splits the screen and shows you a 'live preview' of the markdown result.

Atom is available on `Ubuntu Software` but if you prefer the terminal way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

For rst you can use [this](https://atom.io/packages/rst-preview) and make it work as well.

Comment: Not sure this is what OP asked for - OP wants a WYSIWYG (What you see is what you get) editor that applies the Markdown formatting behind the scenes but only shows them the *rendered* contents and version, not the ability to split and have Live Preview.